# Restrict the number of Jenkins jobs per user

Tags: jenkins

I have my Jenkins configured to visualize jobs (projects) only of the logged in user. I am curious to know is there a way to restrict how many jobs each user is able to create?

Comment: As far as i know, you can only restrict users to create job but there's no limit to number of jobs one can create if he has access to do so.

Comment: That's what I know as well, but I hope there is an option to restrict the number of jobs a user can create